# Check for Multiple Null Values Across Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to check multiple fields for null values in order to create a master field with no null values. In the case below I am attempting to check several "city" fields until I get to a non-null value but this statement is not working as expected.

```
CASE
WHEN b.BillingCity IS NULL THEN b.ShippingCity
WHEN b.BillingCity IS NULL AND b.ShippingCity IS NULL THEN c.BillingCity
WHEN b.BillingCity IS NULL AND b.ShippingCity IS NULL AND c.BillingCity IS NULL THEN b.ES_APP__ESCity__c
WHEN b.BillingCity IS NULL AND b.ShippingCity IS NULL AND c.BillingCity IS NULL AND b.ES_APP__ESCity__c IS NULL THEN b.Avn_City__c
ELSE Null
END
As MasterCity
```

Comment: I think the best answer is to use COALESCE as mentioned in the answer below. But I think it is worth to mention that if you reorder your "WHEN" statements so that the first one will be the last one and the second one will be the third one ... etc, then it will get you the result you need.

Comment: Note that if b.BillingCity IS NULL it will always go to the first condition in your case expression. It does not evaluate each case to see which one is the "most true". You would have to rearrange this entire thing so get the last one at the top and so on.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for the clarification

Comment: But the best approach here by far is coalesce as Lamak answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.BillingCity,b.ShippingCity,c.BillingCity,.....)
```

Comment: @hansolo what do you mean?, it does return the first non null value